# ruby logging convenience method

Tags: ruby, debugging, variables

I would like a ruby method "show" which does this:

```
anyobject.show
```

the output of the call would be:

```
anyvar => _the_ _pp_ _string_ _of_ _the_ _object_
```

Something close , but not quite is :

```
p "any_var => #{any_var.pretty_inspect}"
```

Since you have to type "anyvar" out to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this can't be done because methods are called on objects, not variables.

Edit:

If you're willing to do it with a "function" rather than a method you could add this to Kernel:

```
def show(var)
  print "#{var} => #{eval(var).pretty_inspect}"
end
```

and call it via

```
show "anyvar"
```

It's a bit ugly because of the need to pass the variable name in as a string, of course.

Comment: I changed the brackets a bit:

def show(var)
  print "#{var} => #{eval(var).pretty_inspect}"
end


I tried an irb session with  a = 1 ; then show ("a") ; and it returned "nil" for your version , and "a is an undefined variable" for my version. 

$a = 1 ; show ("$a") ; however, did work. 


This is a clever - but is there a scope issue (does not work for local variables ). ?

Comment: You need to pass the binding of the current context to the `show` method: `def show(var,b); print "#{var} => #{eval(var,b).pretty_inspect}"; end` and then `show "anyvar", binding`

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you're asking. It prints readable info about an object in YAML format:

```
puts YAML::dump(object)
```

So your show method would look like this:

```
def show:
  puts YAML::dump(self)
end
```

and don't forget to:

```
require 'yaml'
```

Comment: no it doesnt. At least not in irb:

>> a = "asdf"
=> "asdf"
>> puts YAML::dump(a)
--- asdf
=> nil

Answer (score 2):

A little enhanced version of Martin's one:

```
require 'pp'
def show(var,bindings) 
  print "#{var} => #{eval('var',bindings).pretty_inspect}"
end

a,t = 1,Time.now
show a,binding #=> a => 1
show t,binding #=> t => Mon Sep 28 13:12:34 +0300 2009
```

Comment: You're not passing the variable name

Comment: i think var name needs to be quoted